# CMake could NOT find Python

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

I'm installing CERN's ROOT package. When I run the `cmake` command, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Python_LIBRARIES
  Python_INCLUDE_DIRS Interpreter Development)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython.cmake:347 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/modules/SearchRootCoreDeps.cmake:70 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:120 (include)
```

Python3 is installed. I tried installing python-dev, but i get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev-is-python2 : Depends: python-is-python2 (= 2.7.17-4) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: python2-dev but it is not going to be installed
 root-system : Depends: root-system-bin but it is not installable
               Depends: libroot-core-dev but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf3d-gl-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-io-xmlparser-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-mathmore-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-unuran-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-misc-memstat-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-misc-table-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-net-bonjour-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-net-ldap-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-graf2d-asimage (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-gui-qt (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-graf2d-qt (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-math-fftw3 (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-math-minuit2 (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-net-krb5 (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-sql-odbc (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-geom-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf2d-gpad-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf2d-graf-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf2d-postscript-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf3d-eve-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-graf3d-g3d-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-gui-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-gui-ged-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-hist-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-hist-spectrum-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-html-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-io-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-foam-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-genvector-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-mathcore-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-matrix-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-minuit-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-mlp-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-physics-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-quadp-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-smatrix-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-math-splot-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-misc-minicern-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-montecarlo-eg-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-montecarlo-vmc-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-net-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-net-auth-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-proof-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-proof-proofplayer-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-tmva-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-tree-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: libroot-tree-treeplayer-dev (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-geom-geombuilder (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-geom-geompainter (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-graf2d-x11 (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-graf3d-x3d (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-gui-fitpanel (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-gui-guibuilder (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-gui-sessionviewer (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-hist-hbook (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-hist-histpainter (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-hist-spectrumpainter (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-io-sql (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-io-xml (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-math-fumili (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-plugin-tree-treeviewer (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-system-proofd (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-system-rootd (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
               Recommends: root-system-doc (>= 5.34.30-0ubuntu8) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, then `apt-get install python-dev`, then `cmake ..`.